# How can I get over the fear of being recorded in music?

Tags: performing, stage-fright

I've started playing the violin about 2 years ago, and I have to admit I have no confidence in my playing at all. Whenever I practise alone, I always feel terrible after and yet when I practise with others I always feel fine. I have a GCSE recording soon and i'm so scared i'll mess it up. Can someone give me advice?

Comment: Why are you afraid exactly? Yoy doubt your skills or are afraid of being treated badly? Or maybe you are scared of not being able to play correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Play something on which you have confidence that no one can play better than you.
You will see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those 'just do it' things.  Just do it.  The more you analyse, the more you'll suffer.  If you want to do it, do it.  If you don't, don't.  The world won't care.  It has too many violin players already!